# Reference request for fiber functor of covering spaces being monadic

Tags: category-theory, covering-spaces, monads

Let $X$ be a nice topological space (locally path-connected and simply connected). Assume also that $X$ is connected and fix a base point $x_0 \in X$. We consider the category $Cov(X)$ of covering spaces of $X$, and the fiber functor $F : Cov (X) \to Sets$ sending $\pi : E \to X$ to $\pi^{-1} (x_0)$. Is there an organized reference detailing the proof that $F$ is a monadic functor, without first developing explicitly the equivalence with sets acted upon by the fundamental group or some other equivalence, but working directly (so in the spirit of Grothendieck's definition of the etale fundamental group)?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what its left adjoint is ? Once you have an adjunction involving the fiber functor do you know how to test monadicity of an adjoint pair ? (Beck's monadicity theorem) it is not that hard but don't know of a reference.

Comment: @jeanmfischer Well, I didn't think too much about all the details, wanted to see if there is a reference. The left adjoint sends the point to the universal cover, but for that one already has to know about the universal cover and so on, so maybe one can deduce the existence of left adjoint by some adjoint functor theorem to avoid this explicit knowledge... And then check that actually the functor $F$ commutes with colimits by some direct check... And so on...